# Getline-removing colon and dealing with extra line

Tags: c++, getline

```
 struct studentinfo
  { 
     string name;
     CompClass class_taken;
     CompClass class_TA;
  };       

 struct CompClass {
    string class_num;
    string class_sem;
  };
```

The input information that will be inputted looks like this...
   John.Smith:15:S13

I have separated the 15(class number) and the S13(class semester), but would   like to keep them as one entire course called Course instead of string num and string sem. However, I'm not sure how to get rid of the colon while doing so. How can i manipulate my code below so it takes care of the colon issue?

```
while(getline(file_one, array[i].name, ':')){           
        getline(file_one,array[i].class_taken.num,':');
        getline(file_one,array[i].class_taken.sem,'\n');
        i++;
}
```

UPDATE: i've kept them separate and now am trying to combine them into a single string...What's wrong with my code below though. The output is skipping some of the lines...

```
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    string course="";
    string num;
    string sem;
    num = array[i].class_taken.class_num;
    sem = array[i].class_taken.class_sem;
    course += num;
    course += sem;
    array[i].class_taken.course = course;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: So basically you want to know how to convert the input from `15:S13` to `15S13`?

Comment: Correct, but without having to separate it into two separate parts. I want it one entire string, opposed to two separate strings

Comment: Well you can read in the whole thing into a string and then use `find` and `erase` or you could read it in separately like you are and then just add the two string back together.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  string course="";
  string num;
  string sem;
  num = array[i].class_taken.class_num;
  sem = array[i].class_taken.class_sem;
  course += num;
  course += sem;
  array[i].class_taken.course = course;
  i++;
 }

Comment: @Lionel: Please look at your last comment.  The code is not very readable.  Please edit your post with the changes.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a second `i++` at the end of `for` block? En passant, a general suggestion: use `++i`, instead of `i++`, when you don't need the old value of variable.